# Redis / Limit of .rdb file

Tags: redis

I use Redis, and it save it .rdb file (every transaction).

I notice that the .rdb on the production grows 15 MB every day (Now it stands on 75 MB).

Is there any limit to the .rdb file? Is this affect on the performance of the Redis DB?

Answer (score 0):

The rdb on disk has no direct impact on the running redis instance.

The only limit seems to be the filesystem.
We have a 10 GB compressed rdb which is in-memory about 28 GB in size and also had much bigger ones.

But, you may encounter interrupts if you save such large datasets like ours to disk. (even if you use http://redis.io/commands/bgsave )
When the forked redis process writes the latest diff, redis is unresponsive until it's completely written to disk. This time span depends on different values like writes during bgsave, overall amount of keys, size of hashes and so on.
And, be sure to correctly set up the "save" configuration depending on your needs.